# Newb with class project issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an issue with JS (with which my knowledge base is not large). Excuse me if this seems like a simple fix, but I cannot figure out what my problem is. I'm pulling from an array, and displaying images with links tied to the images, that lead to an external site. My issue is, I want to display the "genre" underneath the images and JS isn't responding to any of it.

Here's my JS:

```
async function getData(type) {
    const url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&media=podcast&term=' + type;
    const containerElement = window.document.querySelector("." + type + "-content")
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const result = await response.json();
        result.results.map((item) => {
            console.log(item)
          
            const { collectionName, artworkUrl600, trackViewUrl, collectionViewUrl, primaryGenreName } = item;
          
            console.log(collectionName, artworkUrl600, trackViewUrl, collectionViewUrl, primaryGenreName);
          
            const itemElement = window.document.createElement("a");
            itemElement.setAttribute("href", collectionViewUrl);
          
            const collectionNameElement = window.document.createElement("h2");
            const imageElement = window.document.createElement("img");
            const genreElement = window.document.createElement("small");
          
            itemElement.style.marginRight = "20px";
          
            imageElement.classList.add('podcast-image');
          
            genreElement.classList.add('small-genre');
          
            imageElement.setAttribute("src", artworkUrl600);
          
            collectionNameElement.textContent = collectionName;
          
            genreElement.textContent = primaryGenreName;
          
            imageElement.after(genreElement);
          
            itemElement.append(imageElement);
          
            containerElement.append(itemElement);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
getData("popular")
getData("trending")
```

I want the "primaryGenreName" to be present on the site underneath each image pulled. Just can't figure it out, any ideas?

Comment: You never create `containerElement` but you try to append to it.